# Silence detection in Kinect V2

Tags: kinect, winmm, audio-capture, kinect-v2

I am using winmm.dll to record audio from kinect using below method :

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int record(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
```

For now, I am using Stop button click to stops the recording but I want to stop Recording while detecting silence for sometimes.Because I want to remove "StopRecording" button and Stops the recording if the user doesn't speak for 10 seconds.